# Finding the simple average of indicators in cross-sectional time-series data

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, variables, mean

I am working with cross-sectional, time-series data and need to find the simple average for certain variables for each year and each country.

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDhFk.png)

Comment: I'd recommend formatting your data structure differently to increase readability, try a screenshot or format as code, or better yet, giving a small sample of data so users can reproduce issues. What have you tried so far, and where has it failed?

Comment: I have added a screenshot. I am quite new to R so not sure best place to start. What I would like to do is find the average of say 8 different variables for Austria 1999, Austria 2000 etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using subset notation and which statements:

```
mean(tbl_df$unemployment[which(tbl_df$year == 1999 & tbl_df$cname = "Austria")

sapply(tbl_df[tbl_df$year %in% 1999:2003,c("unemployemnt","OTHER COLUMN NAMES")], function(x) mean(x))
```

To breakdown the second operation, the `sapply` function takes 2 main arguments, `data` and `function`. Data is what data you want to look at, `function` is the function you want to apply to the data.

Does this sufficiently answer your question? The logic can be modified in any way, but using [] and which statements will be your bread and butter so to speak

Comment: So if i wanted to find the average of multiple variables for Austria 1999, Austria 2000  etc etc. Is there someway to do this?

Comment: So for instance in the screenshot I have uploaded I would like to get the average of the three variables so would be 08.3 for Austria 1999 - 2000 then Belgium 1999 would be 0.5

Comment: Edited, also this resource may be of help to you https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-tutorial-apply-family

Answer (score 0):

If you learn a bit of tidyverse you can give yourself a bit more flexibility. I made a simple example dataset similar to yours for convenience.

```
> data
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   country years  var1  var2
   <chr>   <int> <int> <int>
 1 A        2001    21    51
 2 A        2002    22    52
 3 A        2003    23    53
 4 A        2004    24    54
 5 A        2005    25    55
 6 B        2001    26    56
 7 B        2002    27    57
 8 B        2003    28    58
 9 B        2004    29    59
10 B        2005    30    60
```

Let's say that you wanted to get the averages for var1 and var2 for each country between the years of 2002 and 2004.

```
data %>%
   filter(between(years, 2002, 2004)) %>%
   group_by(country) %>%
   summarize_at(vars(var1, var2), mean)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
  country  var1  var2
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 A          23    53
2 B          28    58
```

Or if you just wanted to get the average for each year while ignoring country.

```
data %>% 
   group_by(years) %>%
   summarize_at(vars(var1, var2), mean)

# A tibble: 5 x 3
  years  var1  var2
  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1  2001  23.5  53.5
2  2002  24.5  54.5
3  2003  25.5  55.5
4  2004  26.5  56.5
5  2005  27.5  57.5
```

Let's now say that you wanted to get the average of var1 and var2 for each country-year combination.

```
data %>% 
   group_by(country, years) %>% 
   summarize(avg=mean(c(var1, var2)))

# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   country [2]
   country years   avg
   <chr>   <int> <dbl>
 1 A        2001    36
 2 A        2002    37
 3 A        2003    38
 4 A        2004    39
 5 A        2005    40
 6 B        2001    41
 7 B        2002    42
 8 B        2003    43
 9 B        2004    44
10 B        2005    45
```

Comment: Thanks. This is really helpful! So what I would like to do is get the average of var1 and var2 for each country at each year, so there would be an average for var1 and var2 from 1 - 10. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Luke I edited my comment to hopefully address your question.

Comment: Brilliant! That does solve my problem. I do have one more follow up question if that is okay. So if I need to create a new dataset with those averages but then all my other variables included as normal, so there is a var3 that I want to remain as it is, how would i code that?

Comment: @Luke, If each country has each year only once, you could do mutate(data, avg=mean(c(var1,var2)))